# Hazelcast client time to live setup for individual client

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast

I am using SpringBoot with Hazelcast.
In my setup I have one Hazelcast server(3.12.6) up and running I am connecting that with Hazelcast client in my SpringBoot application.

`hazelcast-client.yaml`

```
hazelcast-client:
  network:
    cluster-members:
      - 127.0.0.1
    smart-routing: false
```

I have checked the setup in Hazelcast server, there is a global configuration in `hazelcast.xml` that helps in configuration of Time to live configuration.

`hazelcast.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<group>
    <name>dev</name>
</group>
<management-center enabled="true">http://mc_server:8080/hazelcast-mancenter</management-center>
<map name="default">
    <time-to-live-seconds>10</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>10</max-idle-seconds>
</map>
```

My question is:
Is there any way I can configure time to live and other settings using my springboot client on my server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Dynamic configuration from a Hazelcast Client.

```
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
MapConfig mCfg = new MapConfig("test");
mCfg.setTimeToLiveSeconds(15);
client.getConfig().addMapConfig(mCfg);
HazelcastClient.shutdownAll();
```

Details and limitations are here - https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.6/manual/html-single/index.html#dynamically-adding-data-structure-configuration-on-a-cluster

Thanks, Sharath